# SQL date to a float then back to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, floating-point

Hey all I have the following query:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(CAST(CAST('7/1/2014 9:07:00 AM' as datetime) AS float), 20, 10)) ContactDateTime
```

This query produces this number: **41819.3798611111**

Now what I am needing to do is convert that back to the normal **'7/1/2014 9:07:00 AM**' date (if thats even possible) that it was. However, I am not sure how to go about doing that in MS SQL.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to go Datetime -> Float -> String -> Datetime??

Comment: why are you casting to a float and then back to a date? i think it might help if you explained why you would need to do this because the way it looks right now it seems counterintuitive to convert to a different data type and then back to the original

Comment: It's old code that I can not change so I need to figure out how (if possible) convert that number back to the date. But i do agree with you, @rhealitycheck but its out of my hands.

Comment: Why was someone setting the date as a float in the first place????????????

Comment: @StealthRT - that sucks. so is there no way to access the original date value then? and you basically have <somevalue> which is a float and you're trying to convert it back to a date and you happen to know what the date is, correct?

Comment: Right @rhealitycheck. The **SELECT CAST(41819.3798611111 AS DATETIME)** post works just fine in what i am looking to do. I understand this is an odd way of doing it but like i said, its out of my hands since its old code. Changing that is bound to cause errors for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method for rounding the DateTime to the nearest second:

```
DECLARE @Float FLOAT
SET @Float = 41819.3798611111
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 500 - DATEPART(ms, CAST(@Float AS DATETIME) + '00:00:00.500'), CAST(@Float AS DATETIME))
```

`2014-07-01 09:07:00.000`

Comment: I suppose the relevant question is, how much precision are you looking for? This will get you to the Second.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CAST(41819.3798611111 AS DATETIME)

Comment: The accuracy was lost when casting from DateTime to float. The cast back to DateTime does not make it less accurate.

Comment: The cast back to DataTime may make people think there is more precision than they would expect if they saw a float.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `CAST` it back (just tried in SSMS2012)

```
DECLARE @myFloat FLOAT
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME

SELECT @myFloat = LTRIM(STR(CAST(CAST('7/1/2014 9:07:00 AM' as datetime) AS float), 20, 10))
SELECT @myDate = CAST(@myFloat AS DATETIME)

SELECT @myDate
```

The select shows `2014-07-01 09:06:59.997` for me which is fairly accurate ;)

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@myDate".

Comment: So you're on SQL Server 2005 or older then?

Comment: @StealthRT i edited my post it should work on 2005 as well now

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: @StealthRT ehm I don't understand, so am I! How could it not work for you did you copy the whole code snipped?

Comment: that i did, @DrCopyPaste.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 41819.3798611111)
```

But float seems to be not precise enough so convert gives

```
2014-07-01 09:06:59.997
```

But if you add another 1 at the end:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 41819.37986111111)
```

It gives

```
2014-07-01 09:07:00.000
```